# Ruby: Return if method returns a non-nil value

Tags: ruby, refactoring, guard-clause

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this in Ruby?

```
def my_method(x, y)
  return error if (error = validate(x, y))
  # do something else
end
```

I call `#validate` elsewhere, so to keep things DRY, I have it return the error message.

Comment: Is `validate(x, y)` returning a `Boolean`?

Comment: Normally errors, like exceptions, halt the process. Is their a particular reason why you want to avoid that?  For example when you run my_method, are you then checking afterwards whether an error object is returned before moving on? Otherwise instead of returning error, you can raise error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with this more explicit and more readable version?

```
def my_method(x, y)
  error = validate(x, y)

  if error
    error
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

IMO there is no benefit in writing the shortest possible code. You should always aim to write the most readable and understandable code.

Answer (score 1):

If `validate` returns error when the input is wrong and `nil` otherwise, then you can do:

```
def my_method(x, y)
  validate(x, y) or # do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the same thing would be:

```
 def my_method(x, y)
    unless validate(x, y)
        # do something else
    end
  end
```

This will return the answer to validate if it returns anything.